# Receiving "NOT NULL constraint failed: home_page._order" error in Django model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I keep receiving the above error and I am still not sure what component of my code is violating this. Below is my modely.py:

```
def get_image_path(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join('photos', str(instance.id), filename)


# Create your models here.
class Textbook(models.Model):
    founder = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path, blank=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Page(models.Model):

    textbook = models.ForeignKey(Textbook,related_name="pages",blank=True, null=True)
    page_title = models.CharField(max_length = 256,blank=True, null=True)
    page_num = IntegerRangeField(min_value=0,max_value=256, blank=True, null=True)

    def getTextID(self):
        return self.textbook.id

    def __str__(self):
        return self.page_title


    def iterSave(self):
        pages = self.textbook.pages
        MAX_PAGE = pages.aggregate(Max('page_num'))
        try:
            cpy = pages.get(page_num = self.page_num)
            for page in pages:
                if page.page_num >= self.page_num:
                    obj,created = Page.objects.update_or_create(page_title = page.page_title, page_num = page.page_num+1, textbook = page.textbook)
        except:
            if self.page_num > MAX_PAGE:
                obj,created = Page.objects.update_or_create(page_title = self.page_title, page_num = self.page_num+1, textbook = self.textbook)

    def save(self, *args,**kwargs):
        self.iterSave()
        super(Page,self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class Section(models.Model):
    page = models.ForeignKey(Page,related_name="sections")
    section_title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    text = RichTextField(config_name='awesome_ckeditor')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.section_title
```

I understand it has something to do with the query functions but I am not sure what I have done incorrectly to generate this error.

Here is my admin.py if it helps:

```
admin.site.register(Section)
admin.site.register(Textbook)
admin.site.register(Page)
```

and here is a helper function I have:

```
from django.db import models

class IntegerRangeField(models.IntegerField):
    def __init__(self, verbose_name=None, name=None, min_value=None, max_value=None, **kwargs):
        self.min_value, self.max_value = min_value, max_value
        models.IntegerField.__init__(self, verbose_name, name, **kwargs)
    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        defaults = {'min_value': self.min_value, 'max_value':self.max_value}
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super(IntegerRangeField, self).formfield(**defaults)
```

and my views.py:

```
def index(request):
    books = Textbook.objects.all()
    ret = {}
    for o in books:
        ret[o.id] = o
    ret['books'] = books
    return render(request,'index.html', ret)


def genpage(request, bid = -1, pid = 1):
    b = Textbook.objects.get(id = int(bid))
    page = b.pages.get(page_num = int(pid))
    sections = page.sections.all()
    if  b.pages.filter(page_num = page.page_num+1).exists():
        next_page = page.page_num+1
    else:
        next_page = -1
    if b.pages.filter(page_num = page.page_num-1).exists():
        prev_page = page.page_num-1
    else:
        prev_page = -1

    ret = {
        'prev_page':prev_page,
        'next_page':next_page,
        'book':b,
        'page_title': page.page_title,
        'sections': sections,

    }
```

I am pretty stumped by this because its an error I am so unfamiliar with. The error comes up in relation to calling super in the save function of page but other than that I do not know what to do.

Comment: The error occurs in a model called home page, but you have not included that model in your sample code. Can you add it?

Comment: @voodoo-burger the database table is `home_page` - that's the `Page` model in the `home` app, which is already in the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if your `ForeignKey` used [`order_with_respect_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/options/#order-with-respect-to) at one point, which adds an `_order` field to your model.

Now that you have removed `order_with_respect_to`, you need to remove the field from your database. Hopefully, creating a new migration and migrating will fix the problem.

Comment: You create and run migrations with `./manage.py makemigrations` and `./manage.py migrate` from the command line. If that doesn't work, you can manually drop the column in the db shell (how to do that is a separate question). Avoid manually dropping the column if possible - you don't want your migrations and the db to get out of sync.